# jQuery .get works inline but not in an external file

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404, jquery-get, external-js, url-action

I have some jQuery where I'm loading HTML into a document using a .get, like this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("beneficiary")';
$.get(url, function (response) {
     $('#beneficiaries').append(response);
});
```

It works perfectly when the script is inline, but when I move it to an external .js file, the .get fails and I get an HTTP 404 error. (File not found: http ... /Wizard/@Url.Action("beneficiary")).

The external .js file is WizardScript.js, I'm including it like this (I'm using jQuery UI elsewhere in the script, hence those script tags):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/WizardScript.js"></script>
```

This was working earlier, and I have no idea what happened! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the external file right before the body tag?. Like this:

```
...
...
...
<script src="myExternalFile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that's where it is. BTW this is an ASP.NET MVC using a layout file so some other script tags get added. Probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: @RobertM. so the issue is still there event though you have the file right before the body tag?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.